# Interpreting adjusted R-squared of a log transformed regression model

Tags: regression, transform, logarithm

I am running a linear regression model where the dependent variable (Y) is log-transformed. I am struggling on how to interpret the adjusted R-squared of this log-transformed model that is meaningful. Any insight is very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: After the fit, you will need to de-transform the dependent variable and model predictions, and then manually calculate.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more what do you mean by manual calculation and how to perform it?

Comment: I calculate R-squared (R2) as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" and the R-squared adjusted (R2adj) as "R2adj = 1.0 - (1.0 - R2)*((number_of_data_points - 1.0)/(number_of_data_points-number_of_parameters))"

Comment: @JamesPhillips If the relationship is assumed to be linear when the outcome is logged, why should OP back-transform the predictions to calculate an $R^2$?

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim one of the reasons is that the R-squared calculation I wrote in my comment requires variance of the dependent variable, not variance of the log(dependent variable).

Comment: @JamesPhillips that's circular. If you write that formula, of course you will need to back transform. Why are you writing that formula?

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim My understanding of the OP's question regards the modeling of Y.

Comment: Log-transformed Y is my outcome variable, so the interpretation of R-squared is something like '35% of the variability in the log-transformed Y is accounted for....' this is where I am hesitant. This interpretation is not very intuitive to me. I am interpreting the exponent of the coefficients of this model which I think is more intuitive than interpreting just the coefficients. I was looking for a way to better interpret the R-squared of this log-transformed model.

Comment: @JamesPhillips but the model is a model for log Y not Y. Of course, you can still look at prediction quality on the scale of Y.

Answer (score 4):

Is the model of log-transformed Y the only model you are considering? Then you can just interpret the (unadjusted) R-squared in the usual way.  For example, if the R-squared is 70%, then 70% of the variability in the log-transformed values of Y is accounted for by the predictor variables included in the model.

If you are considering several competing models for the log-transformed Y, then it makes sense to compare their explanatory power via the adjusted R-squared. In that case, the model with the highest value for the adjusted R-squared would be preferred - as explained, for example, here: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/multiple-regession-analysis-use-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared-to-include-the-correct-number-of-variables.

Comment: How then can the model's explanatory power for the variability in the non-log-transformed values of Y be calculated?

Comment: @JamesPhillips R-squared is a model fit statistic. By modeling the log transformed Y, you are automatically claiming that it makes sense to think of this outcome on the log scale. In fact, predictors have a better linear relationship to the outcome on this scale. To all intents and purposes, the log transformed Y is your outcome. You just happened to measure its non log transformed counterpart.

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim My understanding of the OP's question regards the modeling of Y.

Comment: @Isabella Thank you for your answer. Yes, I understand that I can interpret the R-squared in the usual way except for the fact that it accounts for the variability of log-transformed Y instead of Y. However, this interpretation is a bit difficult to grasp. I was wondering if it can be interpreted which is more intuitive? For example, for this model, I am interpreting the exponent of the coefficients for better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: @curiousmind: The difficulty in interpretation arises from log-transforming the response and it's not confined to the interpretation of the R-squared. If you want to compute the mean of the original response or predict from this model via back-transformation, you will likely need to consider a smearing factor. Perhaps you can consider an alternate model (e.g., Gamma regression model, if supported by your data), so that you are modeling the mean of the outcome variable directly and avert the need to use a smearing factor following back-transformation from log to original outcome scale.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: @curiousmind Have you tried @ IsabellaGhement 's approach ?